# Not able to read as well as write data in firebase database

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase cloud server to save the data of the user when using a mobile device via expo. The information is not getting saved(or read) in the firebase database. But on using firebase functions like

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

the data gets stored in the Authentication tab of firebase console.

```
  createNewUser: (userData) => {
return firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc(`${userData.uid}`)
  .set(userData);
}
```

But  on the running this(the code above) the information of the user is not getting saved in the  firebase database.

I tried the same running on the web browser and it works just fine(storing data on database as well as on the authentication tab) but not on mobile devices. My friend has the same code and it works fine for him.

After many attempts i came to a realization that on using mobile devices, my server is not able to send information to the firebase cloud service. [this is the snapshot of the no of request firebase cloud service got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvcX1.png). The snapshot shows that it has not received an requests which is not true I have sent it many requests.

I get an error saying

```
Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
```

`(Saw setTimeout with duration 3299524ms)`

But the same error is being shown on my friends device so i don't think that the possible reason for the issue is this.

Can anyone tell what could be the possible issue here, please. THANK YOU